# Force update not working in my componentwillreceiveprops in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using componentwillReceiveProps to update the changes in render method.

Here my props returns a value after few seconds (i.e) while navigating to the screen it returns empty value and then it get returning value in my props).

```
<Names.js/> ==> passing studentslist to StudentsScreen (It returns the value after sometime) 

<StudentsScreen.js/> this.props.studentlist not get updated here.
```

studentScreen.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const nextstudentCount = nextProps.studentslist && nextProps.studentslist.length;
    console.log("nextstudentCount" + nextstudentCount)
    const curStudentCount = this.props.studentslist && this.props.studentslist.length;

    const {expanded} = this.state;

    this.forceUpdate())
    if (curStudentCount === 0 && nextStudentCount > curStudentCount && expanded) {
      this.state.height.setValue(300);
    }
  }
```

Note: It occurs first time. If I navigate back and come forth it get worked fine.

forceUpdate not working fine.

How can I update this props while navigating to the screen in first time

Comment: can you show your code in componentwillReceiveProps method?

Comment: @MahendraPratap I have updated above